# Nginx location match multiple extensions unless path starts with specific word

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-negation, nginx-location, nginx-config

How can I write a location block that matches any path ending in the following extensions:

jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|json|xml|txt|html

Unless the path starts with "/rails" (eg: /rails/randomstring/image.png)?

I currently have this basic block:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|json|xml|txt|html)$ {
  gzip_static on;
  gzip on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

But this would match "/rails/randomstring/image.png" and I don't want that.

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/816998/nginx-rule-match-all-paths-except-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can anchor a negative lookahead to the beginning of the string:

```
^(?!\/rails).*(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|json|xml|txt|html)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/in03aO/1)

Comment: I tried a negative lookahead before but I must've done something wrong, this one works perfectly. Thank you!